# Correcting truncated zip codes in Magento through SQL query

Tags: sql, magento

Zip codes with leading zeroes were truncated without the zeroes after a migration from X-Cart to Magento. I'm trying to run a SQL query to add the zeroes back but don't know which table/column to run it against in the database. We use the zip code to determine which shipping services will be available to the customer during checkout. Does anyone know where the shipping address (both default and additional) zip codes are located in the database?

Answer (score 3):

The zip / postal code in magento is an attribute of the customer_address entity.

Look in the table mage_eav_attribute to find what the is attribute id and where it is stored, e.g. execute this query to find out where magento is storing the attribute:

```
select attribute_id
, backend_type
, attribute_code
from mage_eav_attribute 
where attribute_code like '%post%' or attribute_code like '%zip%'
```

For my implementation, the `attribute_id = 29`, `attribute_code = 'postcode'` and `backend_type` = 'varchar'. The column `backend_type` will tell you what kind of attribute this is on the backend.

`varchar` tells me that magento stores this attribute in a table called mage_customer_address_entity_varchar. *For you this might be different because it seems to treat it as an integer and truncate leading zeros.*

Then I can execute the following sql to get the postcodes. *Of course, you'd have to modify the attribute table `mage_customer_address_entity_varchar` to where your implementation of magento is storing this attribute.*

```
select e.entity_id, a.value atype.attribute_code
from mage_customer_address_entity e
join mage_customer_address_entity_varchar a ON a.entity_id = e.entity_id
join mage_eav_attribute atype ON atype.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
where atype.attribute_code = 'postcode'
```

Finally, you need this for shipping addresses (and not billing addresses?). Default shipping addresses are attributes of customer, so you'll have to modify my above approach to find which customer attribute table contains that information.

I hope this helps you figure out your solution

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

could it be possible for you to just ignore theses leading 0? since for the logic of the system it doesn't matter and if you have to print it, just get the length of the string and add the leading 0 as a string if you want/need to.

If that doesn't work for you, you will have to look into source code of the module you are using to see wich table the module uses.

Comment: The leading zeroes are needed to calculate UPS shipping options. Certain UPS shipping options won't show up if there are less then 5 digits in the zip code. The only workaround we've found is to have the customer edit their address through account settings and add the zero/zeroes back to the zip code so that all UPS shipping options are shown at checkout.